# Custom ToolBar not there

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

I have decided to make my own Tool bar

So i removed the regular ToolBar :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar> //removetollbar
```

and make my own tool bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then i include in main xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/customtoolbar"
    android:id="@+id/custombar" >

</include>
```

and in the code i set it up :

```
_CustomToolBar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) 
findViewById(R.id.custombar);
setSupportActionBar(_CustomToolBar);
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar _CustomToolBar;
```

> now when the app run the custom toolbar is not there

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean to say activity opens but toolbar is not visible?

Answer (score 1):

In your `<include>` tag, you've set the id of the toolbar to be `@+id/custombar`, but you're looking it up using `R.id.toolbar`. Change that line to this:

```
_CustomToolBar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.custombar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get your question clearly, but still I will post how I code to set custom toolbar.

1) My Manifest have NoActionBar theme to remove default toolbar.

2) My custom_toolbar.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

3) Way I include it in my main.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />
```

4) My Java code -

```
// In onCreate method
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar _CustomToolBar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(_CustomToolBar);
```

And it is working properly.

[image]

So Here whats the different between our code.

1) Give your custom toolbar proper id `android:id="@+id/customToolbar"` instead of giving it to you `include`. 
2) Give height and background color to your custom toolbar so that it will be visible properly

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

3) And instead of linking `include id` to toolbar, link your `custom toolbar id`

```
findViewById(R.id.customToolbar);
```